# Why isn't this mod_rewrite re-directing?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm sending every request through an index.php except for pages in my blog subdirectory.  I've been able to do this using mod_rewrite in my parent folder and;

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

]

However, I'd also like to send requests to my blog folder if they have the form:

documentation/some-file.

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/documentation/(.+)$ https://www.some_domain.com/blog/documentation/$1
```

but it *looks* like my request isn't getting sent to the blog folder in this case.  My full code is below:

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect to index.php as appropriate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^/documentation/(.+)$ https://www.some_domain.com/blog/documentation/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Edit:

I've used a slightly modified version of @Rijul's suggestion below and after moving the RewriteRule to before the RewriteCond, it works as I had hoped.  In other words, the re-write for documentation performs the re-write to the blog subfolder.  And, all other requests go through my index.php file.  At this point, I would like to understand why.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^documentation/?(.*)$ /blog/documentation/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect to index.php as appropriate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i know

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Without this all the rewrite rules and condition will be ignore

```
RewriteRule ^documentation/?(.*)$ /blog/documentation/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Rewrites documentation to blog/documentation

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This rewrite condition checks whether the requested directory name doesn't exits. If it doesn't exits. Then proceeds to the next condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This rewrite condition checks whether the requested file name doesn't exits. If it doesn't exits. Then proceeds to the next condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

This rewrite condition checks whether the requested symbolic link doesn't exits. If it doesn't exits. Then proceeds to rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Rewrite to index.php?url=

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

writing rewrite condition like this produces an and operation.

> (no file exits in that name) and (no directory exits in that name) and
>   (no symbolic link exits in that name)

If this is true then rewrite to php file. *(no directory exits in that name)* will go false in the case for */blog* (since such a directory exits)

Comment: It's half working!  Now if I put in documentation/something it works great.  However, now it's not doing any of my "non-documentation" redirects.  For example, I'm not convinced that it ever makes it to the last line in the "general" case.

Comment: Can you provide a sample url that is not working and its expected result

Comment: For example, www.my_domain.com/authenticate/show-user-login-form should go to my login page (which it does without the code above).  Or, something as basic as www.my_domain.com should be routed through index.php and show the homepage.  Neither is happening.

Comment: So, I've been playing around with it and moved the documentation rewrite line to right before #redirect to index.php as appropriate and it seems to be working.  If you or someone else could explain why it's working now, then I'd be happy to give credit as the solution.

Comment: Is your www.my_domain.com/blog still working as you expected after that change you made?

Comment: I simply doubt that it will work. I tried again with the htaccess code above and it is working for me. Can you please copy paste the above code and try again.

Comment: _<?php
    echo $_GET['url'];
    ?>_    Create a PHP file with this code and name it as index.php and then see the php echo to confirm.

Comment: I may have been unclear about the code that now works.  Please see my edited post above.